# broken lug bolt - nut still on - can't remove wheel

Tags: lug-nut, scion, wheel-lugs

I was replacing the brake pads on my 2014 Scion XB and the lug bolt is broken. I can't put enough pressure on the nut to take it off as the bolt with the nut can just jostle around even going in and out. the bolt is definitely broken but with the nut still on I can't take the wheel off and in turn neither can I replace the bolt. I can't find anything on what to do in such a situation anywhere online even though there's countless tutorials and videos on how to replace the bolt. I just need to take off the nut.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the lug actually broken, or is it turning inside the hub? If turning inside the hub, you might be able to put pressure on the wheel (or have someone do it for you) and turn the lug nut off that way. By putting pressure on the tire, it might catch inside of the hub where it's supposed to be. The reason I'm thinking this is the case is because of it was actually broken and you have the rest of the nuts off, the wheel would come off with the lug stuck inside of it.

Comment: Some lugs have mushroom heads so if the splines fail they just rotate in the hub... @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2

Comment: @SolarMike - That's exactly what I'm talking about. If the splines are spinning, putting pressure on the mushroom can give it enough grip to get the nut off. Thanks for the add.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 just trying to help your explanation. But who cares.

Comment: Is the nut recessed? If it projects or you have enough access you could use a nut splitter.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like drilling the nut until it splits is about your only choice.

Have a wheel on my car showing evidence of this.

Make a shield to protect the wheel from the drill and don’t break the drill in the nut.